# SugarCRM 'Bad data Passed in' in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sugarcrm

SugarCRM **getting the TOKEN** , works fine locally but when tried on Google App engine gives an error [500] saying

```
 "Bad data passed in;<a href="......."> Return to Home</a>
```

Here I get data from the user in to a dictionary *crm_details* which is then used in request sending.
My request is as follows,

```
url = "https://" + crm_details['instance'] + "/rest/v10/oauth2/token"
payload = {"password": crm_details['password'],
                       "username": crm_details['crm_admin'],
                       "client_id": crm_details['key_name'], "platform": "base",
                       "client_secret": crm_details['key']}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the **platform** .
When integrating SugarCRM a new platform has to be added to the files.

> When working directly with the filesystem, enable the disable_unknown_platforms configuration by setting $sugar_config['disable_unknown_platforms'] = true in your ./config_override.php. This will prevent the system from allowing unknown platform types from accessing the rest endpoints. Next, create a file in ./custom/Extension/application/Ext/Platforms/ to map a new platform in the system. The following example adds a new platform called 'integration' that can be used throughout the system:

It will work right after that.